# AngularJS $http response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

here is my code

```
var object = null
app.controller("controller",function($scope,service){
    $scope.search=function(){
        service.findData().then(
            function successCallback(response){
                object = response.data
            },
            function errorCallback(response){
                alert("error")
            }
        )
        console.log(object)
    }
})
```

when I print the object, it is null so the question is: how can I get response.data outside?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: write `console.log` inside your success callback. You are working with Promises, you can't get the data out. You can assign it to a scoped variable with `$scope.object = ...` and then display it with `{{object}}` for example

Comment: yep,i know $scope.object can work,but i want this object to do other things in controller ,so i want to use object out of findData()

Comment: then you have to keep your entire logic inside that success callback. Or you can return the Promise, but if you want any data from it, you would need to resolve it every time with `.then` and still keep the logic inside the Promise

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I dont think doing the logic inside a sucesscallback is a good option. You can make a reference to the controller  and write a controller function as done below in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a general practice during the era of AngularJS to assign the controller to variable.

```
app.controller("controller",function($scope,service){
    var self = this;
    $scope.search=function(){
        service.findData().then(
            function successCallback(response){
                self.yourBusinessFunction (response.data)

            },
            function errorCallback(response){
                alert("error")
            }
        )
        console.log(object)
    }

    self.yourBusinessFunction = function(data){

    console.log(data);
    // data here will be the response.data from the service
    // You can write your logic here

    }


})
```

Comment: tks,i hava another question,if i hava 2 response with 2 search method ,how can i use one self.bussinessFunction to handle two response.data

Comment: sync both responses with `$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(response_array){...})`

Comment: thx,i think i can solve it today :)

Comment: It is easy to work from the above basics ryt. On the success callback of the second service method, call the business functions. if you need another business function, write it as a property of `self` like `self.businessFunction2` in th same controller and use it likewise.

Comment: i get it,this seems to be easier;

Comment: I've done it ,thx!